# Multiple ModelAdmins/views for same model in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

How can I create more than one ModelAdmin for the same model, each customised differently and linked to different URLs?

Let's say I have a Django model called Posts. By default, the admin view of this model will list all Post objects.

I know I can customise the list of objects displayed on the page in various ways by setting variables like list_display or overriding the `queryset` method in my ModelAdmin like so:

```
class MyPostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'pub_date')

    def queryset(self, request):
        request_user = request.user
        return Post.objects.filter(author=request_user)

admin.site.register(MyPostAdmin, Post)
```

By default, this would be accessible at the URL `/admin/myapp/post`. However I would like to have multiple views/ModelAdmins of the same model. e.g `/admin/myapp/post` would list all post objects, and `/admin/myapp/myposts` would list all posts belonging to the user, and `/admin/myapp/draftpost` might list all posts that have not yet been published. (these are just examples, my actual use-case is more complex)

You cannot register more than one ModelAdmin for the same model (this results in an `AlreadyRegistered` exception). Ideally I'd like to achieve this **without** putting everything into a single ModelAdmin class and writing my own 'urls' function to return a different queryset depending on the URL.

I've had a look at the Django source and I see functions like `ModelAdmin.changelist_view` that could be somehow included in my urls.py, but I'm not sure exactly how that would work.

**Update**: I've found one way of doing what I want (see below), but I'd still like to hear other ways of doing this.

Answer (score 359, accepted):

I've found one way to achieve what I want, by using proxy models to get around the fact that each model may be registered only once.

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'pubdate','user')

class MyPost(Post):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

class MyPostAdmin(PostAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return self.model.objects.filter(user = request.user)


admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
admin.site.register(MyPost, MyPostAdmin)
```

Then the default `PostAdmin` would be accessible at `/admin/myapp/post` and the list of posts owned by the user would be at `/admin/myapp/myposts`.

After looking at http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels, I've come up with the following function utility function to do the same thing:

```
def create_modeladmin(modeladmin, model, name = None):
    class  Meta:
        proxy = True
        app_label = model._meta.app_label

    attrs = {'__module__': '', 'Meta': Meta}

    newmodel = type(name, (model,), attrs)

    admin.site.register(newmodel, modeladmin)
    return modeladmin
```

This can be used as follows:

```
class MyPostAdmin(PostAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return self.model.objects.filter(user = request.user)

create_modeladmin(MyPostAdmin, name='my-posts', model=Post)
```

Comment: this is awesome. i wasn't aware that a proxy model could be registered in the admin site. this will actually help me greatly.

Comment: I also needed to register the same models twice in django admin and proxy models seem to work. But I found one problem with the permission system. See here:
http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11154

Comment: Its also a good idea to change the default manager instead of the ModelAdmin queryset. So behaviour of the proxy model is consistent even outside the admin.

Comment: Now the real answer is, why django doesn't let you have two admin's for the same model? we shouldn't need to hack around things for just 2 lines that checks that and throws an error :s. Great answer still!

Comment: @zzart: there is a pending pull request, which appears to be just missing docs: https://github.com/django/django/pull/146/files

Comment: @bjunix changing the manager does not really work, because you do not have request.user there (always).

Comment: Brilliant. Working with django and particularly admin section, i never knew this could happen.

Comment: FYI this solution has one downside: if you are updating a field via the generated model admin, which is part of the `queryset` filtration, Django is going to pop up with a 404 error on save, because once filtered, the record is not going to be part of the queryset anymore. Probably it is worth to be mentioned.

Comment: for django 1.10 the class delecrations were not correct
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

class MyPost(Post):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

class MyPostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
admin.site.register(MyPost, MyPostAdmin)

Comment: Very helpful! Beside, Django2.2 support proxy model permission management.

Answer (score 3):

Paul Stone answer is absolutely great! Just to add, for Django 1.4.5 I needed to inherit my custom class from `admin.ModelAdmin`

```
class MyPostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        return self.model.objects.filter(id=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the correct answers, I monkeypatch the `AdminSite` class and add the method `register_via_proxy` to make the task easier.

```py
import re
from django.contrib import admin

def _register_proxy(self, model, admin_class):
    proxy_model = type(
        admin_class.__name__, (model,), {
            "__module__": re.sub(
                r'(^.*?)(\.[^\.]+)$', r'\1.proxy', model.__module__
            ),
            "Meta": type("Meta", tuple(), {
                "proxy": True,
                 "app_label": model._meta.app_label
            })
        }
    )

    return self.register(proxy_model, admin_class)


admin.sites.AdminSite.register_via_proxy = _register_proxy
```

And to use is like:

```py
site = admin.sites.AdminSite()
site.register_via_proxy(models.ModelType, AdminClass)
```