# Is there a way to have separate pages for inline admin forms in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Lets say i have a model A.  Then, i have several models B, C, D, E etc that each have a foreignKey to model A.  I know that i can set B, C, D etc as inlines to model A so that when i create a model A it will show formsets for adding multiple items for each subModel, but i think this would make a fairly cluttered and very large page.

Is there a way to somehow, instead of having all of these formsets inline on the same page, to have each formset on a separate page?  in other words, there would be links from model A to create/edit associate model B's, create/edit associated model C's, etc?

Thanks!

Comment: no answers?  it seems like this would be a common use case?

Answer (score 2):

I’m looking for a way to do exactly the same thing. It looks like the answer might be 'proxy models'. It's suggested as an answer to this Stack Overflow query:

> [django admin: separate read-only view and change view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680631/django-admin-separate-read-only-view-and-change-view/6681202#6681202)

…and this query asking about multiple admin lists for the same model:

> [Multiple ModelAdmins/views for same model in Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223375/multiplue-modeladmins-views-for-same-model-in-django-admin/2228821#2228821)

Documentation on Proxy Models here:

> [Django | Models | Django documentation#Proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models)

I’m a newcomer to Django myself, so will post a more complete reply once I get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The trivial answer would be to create a file:

```
${TEMPLATE_DIR}/admin/app/modelA/change_form.html
```

Inside your change form, you do this:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block after_related_objects %}
<ul>
   <li><a href="/admin/app/modelB/{{ original.modelB.id }}/">Edit modelB</a></li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

It's kinda primitive, but it does what you want.  Lists and complex aggregations are trickier, and you'd want to test for original's presence to make sure you don't generate template errors.