# Django admin: two change lists on the same page

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to make an overview page for one of my models I have read through all of http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/.chapter17/ and understand how I can add my own custom views for a model to the django admin.

What I am currently trying to do is add multiple filtered change lists (presenting some child models) onto my "overview" page for the model. In these I would like to be able to make use of some of the admin features such as editable fields or actions.

Does anyone have some pointers on how I can best get started with this.

Comment: What is "multiple filtered change lists"?

Comment: I mean having two or more of the change lists that are usually found in the admin one my page ( the changelist is the page in admin that lists the instances of a model

Answer (score 1):

[Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223375/multiplue-modeladmins-views-for-same-model-in-django-admin)

He created a proxy model for the original model to avoid the conflict. You can create a new model admin or inherit the old ModelAdmin(as shown in the link)