# Getting the different model views to work for the same model in Django-admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to get two model views for the same model in django-admin and i am refering to this:[Multiple model views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223375/multiplue-modeladmins-views-for-same-model-in-django-admin) and seem to have some problem in getting it solved.

Code:

```
from models import Student

class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('displayname', 'StudentID','Parent_First_Name')
    search_fields = ['displayname',]

    def StudentID(self, obj):
      return '%s' % obj.pk
    StudentID.short_description = 'StudentID'
    def Parent_First_Name(self, obj):
        try:
            adult = obj.relationships.filter(role=StudentAdultRelationship.PARENT)[0].adult
            return '%s' % adult.profile.lastname
        except Exception:
            return ''
```

Error: 'function' object has no attribute 'fields'.

Not sure where the error is. Need some guidance on where the error is...

Comment: If nothing else, you're missing ' in list_display = ('StudentID','Teacher_First_Name', ')

Comment: i cut short code when i placed the question in stackoverflow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to change :

`def ChildTeacherAdmin(StudentAdmin):`

to

`class ChildTeacherAdmin(StudentAdmin):`

Comment: gives me this error now: global name 'student' is not defined

Comment: @lakesh In `StudentID` method return `obj.pk` instead of `student.pk`