# How can i have two ModelAdmin of the same model in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

I have the Model Admin like this registered on admin site

```
site.register(Student, ModelAdmin)
```

Now i have one more admin which is inherited from Model Admin with some custom data like this

```
class StudentAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'user', 'created')
    search_fields = ('username',)
```

which i also want to registered like this

```
site.register(Student, StudentAdmin)
```

But then i get the error that `Student` is already registered

Comment: Why do you still want to do `site.register(Student, ModelAdmin)` if `StudentAdmin` does the same thing, only customized?

Comment: Actually i am overiding some more methods and changing some views completly. so if someone type `/student` then it goes to default chnagelist page but when i type '/mystudent' then i will be calling the custom chnagelist view with different stuff in it

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use your subclass for both types of views using GET parameters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple ModelAdmins/views for same model in Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223375/multiple-modeladmins-views-for-same-model-in-django-admin)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps you can use [proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/#proxy-models)
Like..

```
class MyStudent(Student):
    class Meta:
        proxy=True

class MyStudentAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'user', 'created')
    search_fields = ('username',)

site.register(Student, ModelAdmin)
site.register(MyStudent, MyStudentAdmin)
```

Answer (score -2):

First you have to unregister your register declarement

```
site.register(Student, ModelAdmin)
```

with

```
site.unregister(Student, ModelAdmin)
```

and then register second

```
site.register(Student,StudentAdmin)
```

You can not use both at the same time . (1 Model - 1 AdminModel)

Answer (score -5):

### No, you cannot register more than one `ModelAdmin` (sub)class for a single `Model`.

`django.contrib.auth` will raise an error if you attempt this.