# two admin classes for one model django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I need to use one model in context of 2 admin classes. So, this is my model:

```
ITEM_STATUSES = (
('pending', _('Waiting approval')),
('approved', _('Approved')),
('declined', _('Declined'))
)

class Item(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
description = models.TextField(blank=True)
...
status = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=ITEM_STATUSES)
...
```

And I want to use it twice. First, I want to show all the models, like:

```
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  pass

admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
```

And also, I want a new page, where will be shown only models with status = 'pending', like that:

```
class ItemAdminPending(admin.ModelAdmin):
def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(ItemAdminPending, self).queryset(request)
    return qs.filter(status='pending')

admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdminPending)
```

But of course I get an error:
AlreadyRegistered: The model Item is already registered

Any suggestions? Hope to get help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Very close! What you want is to add a [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) in your `models.py`:

```
class ItemPending(Item):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

And then register the second `ModelAdmin` like so:

```
admin.site.register(ItemPending, ItemAdminPending)
```

Comment: There is also this answer which provides a utility function for doing this DRYly https://stackoverflow.com/a/2228821/1302095

Comment: When I add 'using proxy true', then I am able to delete the object.