# Django Inlining shows additional fields in the add dialog

Tags: django

I wrote this django 1.7.7 code:

```
class Color(models.Model):                                                          
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)                    
    def __unicode__(self):                                                          
        return str(self.color)                                                      

class Pen(models.Model):                                                            
    label = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)                       
    color = models.ForeignKey('Color')

class PenAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):                                                   
    pass                                                                         

class PenInline(admin.TabularInline):                                               
    model = Pen                                                                     

class ColorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):                                                 
    inlines = [PenInline,]                                                          

admin.site.register(Pen, PenAdmin)                                                  
admin.site.register(Color, ColorAdmin)
```

I want to know why when I click on the add color button in the admin page, it also shows 3 pen fields as in the image below and how to remove them from that specific dialog.
I've tried both TabularInline and StackedInline and they look identical.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InlineModelAdmin` `extra`'s default value is `3`, so you can simply change it `extra = 0` in `PenInline` declaration:

```
class PenInline(admin.TabularInline):                                               
    model = Pen
    extra = 0
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.extra

**Or** look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2228821/3033586

**Or** remove `ColorAdmin` declaration and change last line to `admin.site.register(Color)`