# With Django 1.8's show_change_link, "Save" button returns to wrong page

Tags: python, django

As a new feature in Django 1.8, we have `InlineModelAdmin.show_change_link`, which, in the words of the documentation,

> Specifies whether or not inline objects that can be changed in the admin have a link to the change form.

This is great, and I've been looking for this feature to be added for a long time.

Just one problem.

Say I'm on the admin change form for an instance of some model that has inlines (e.g., consider the `Poll` model, with `Choice` inlines, from the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial02/#adding-related-objects)). I use the new "Change" link to go to the full change form for one of the `Choice`s. I make some edits and click "Save".

I would expect to be taken back where I came from — that is, to the change form for the `Poll` instance. Instead, I am taken to the list of all `Choice` instances.

How can I have Django remember that if I came from a list of inlines, I should go back there on "Save"? (But if I ever *do* edit the `Choice` directly from the list of all `Choice`s, I *should* go back there.)

Answer (score 1):

You can make Django go back to the Poll instance by overriding the `response_change` method on the full Choice admin:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class ChoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    '''
    To be called from the Poll choice inline. It will send control back 
    to the Poll change form, not the Choice change list.
    '''
    fields = [...]

    def response_change(self, request, choice):
        if not '_continue' in request.POST:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("admin:appname_poll_change", args=(choice.poll.id,)))
        else:
            return super(ChoiceAdmin, self).response_change(request, choice)
```

To address the second part of your question: I think you'll have to register a second, unmodified, admin on the model. You can do that using a proxy model. See [Multiple ModelAdmins/views for same model in Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223375)