# How to make field editable not for all instances in django admin list view?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

How to make field editable not for all instances in django admin list view. For example if sum exists make some field only for this instance editable.

I tried override `ModelForm` and add widget but it doesn't work. Also I tried override `has_permission` function but it doesn't work too.

[image]

UPDATE

I found same issue but I don't know how to get model instance for checking in `get_list_editable`

[Django conditional admin list_editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33416059/django-conditional-admin-list-editable)

Comment: what do you mean by editable?, so that `status` choiceField will be disabled, or object can't be selected for action?

Comment: status choiceField will be disabled

Answer (score 0):

To make field editable not for all instances in django admin list view you should override `_construct_form` in `BaseModelFormSet`.

Add this code before `return form`:

```
    if kwargs['instance'].status == 0: # check field status
        form.fields['status'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'
```