# use custom method instead of __unicode__/__str__ for a Model?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have two models,

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first_name

    def get_last_name(self):
        return self.last_name

    def get_full_name(self):
        return (self.first_name + self.surname + self.last_name)

class House(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    persons = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
    house_number = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

and the models are registered on the admin site.

```
@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

@admin.register(House)
class HouseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

For the model `Person`, I want admin site to display the method `get_full_name()` instead of `__unicode__()`, and `get_last_name` on the `ManyToManyField` of the model `House`.

How can I make this work?

thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, for `Person` you want `get_full_name()` in admin, but `first_name` everywhere else?

Comment: @MikeCovington, for the `person`, I want  the person management url, `/admin/app/person` to display `get_full_name()`, and `get_last_name` on the `ManyToManyField` of Model `House` and  `first_name` everywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

To get the `PersonAdmin` to use `get_full_name`, just use `get_full_name` in [`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

```
@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['get_full_name']
```

To customize the way that a person is displayed in a many to many field, [override the `label_from_instance` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield).

```
from django.forms import ModelMultipleChoiceField

class PersonLastNameChoiceField(ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.get_last_name
```

Define a model form that uses your custom field,

```
class HouseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    persons = models.PersonLastNameChoiceField(Person.objects.all())
```

then use the model form in your model admin.

```
@admin.register(House)
class HouseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = HouseForm
```

Comment: where should I place `PersonLastNameChoiceField` ?

Comment: Wherever you want. Of you only use it in the model admin, then `admin.py` is fine. If you reuse it somewhere else, then you might want to have a separate module e.g. `fields.py`, and import it.

Answer (score 1):

Read abount Proxy Models. A typical usecase for proxy models is to overwrite the Python behavior of a model, by changing its default manager or class methods.

```
class PersonAdmin(Person):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.get_full_name()
```

For more read this: [Multiple ModelAdmins/views for same model in Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223375/multiple-modeladmins-views-for-same-model-in-django-admin)