# How to have multiple ModelAdmins for same model and a consistent admin url returned by reverse()?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

> Django 1.11.28

I have multiple admin views for my Car model as described in [Multiple ModelAdmins/views for same model in Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223375/multiple-modeladmins-views-for-same-model-in-django-admin)

*car/models.py*

```
class Car(models.model):
    ...
    
class ProxySportCar(Car):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        
class ProxyLuxuryCar(Car):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

*car/admin.py*

```
class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

admin.site.register(Car, CarAdmin)


class ProxySportCarAdmin(CarAdmin):
    model = ProxySportCar
    ...

admin.site.register(ProxySportCar, ProxySportCarAdmin)

class ProxyLuxuryCarAdmin(CarAdmin):
    model = ProxyLuxuryCar
    ...

admin.site.register(ProxyLuxuryCar, ProxyLuxuryCarAdmin)
```

My problem is that when i use `reverse`, Django will return one random admin path amongst the model and proxy ones.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
 
reverse("admin:admin_car", kwargs={"car_id": Car.objects.last().pk})
# Return one of :
# u'/admin/car/car/710178/'
# u'/admin/car/proxysportcar/710178/'
# u'/admin/car/proxyluxurycar/710178/'
```

**Is it possible to keep the proxy admin views while having `reverse` always return the base admin path (ie `/admin/car/car/` in my case) ?**